# Prove the following integral identity.

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

> Consider the integrable functions $f, g: [a,b] \rightarrow
> > \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $$\hspace{5cm} g(x) \ge 0 \hspace{3cm}
>  \forall x \in [a, b]$$
>
> and $$m = \inf(f)$$ $$M = \sup(f)$$
>
> there exists a $c \in [m, M]$ such that:
>
> $$\int_a^b f(t)g(t) dt = c \cdot \int_a^b g(t)dt$$

When I think about it, it doesn't seem so far fetched. If we have two functions on the interval $[a, b]$, then it obviously seems reasonable that there exists a $c_1 \in [m, M]$ such that
$$f(x) = c_1$$
, with $x \in [a,b]$. So we would have:

$$f(x)g(x) = c_1 g(x)$$

We could find a $c_k$ for every point $x \in [a, b]$, so that means that we can integrate the above relation and get:

$$\int_a^b f(t) g(t)dt = c \cdot \int_a^b g(t)dt$$

where $c$ is a some sort of linear combination (I think, I'm not sure) of all of the $c_k$'s that I used for every point in the interval $[a, b]$.

What's a better, more concise proof to this identity than the weird and incomplete one that I came up with?

Comment: This question is not the same as the linked question. For example, if $$f(f)=\begin{cases}1&x\ge1\\0&x<1\end{cases}$$ and $a=0$, $b=2$ it satisfies the hypothesis of the current theorem but not the mean value theorem. The current theorem has less restrictive conditions but proves a weaker result. I'm sick of taking time to post answers and having them deleted by moderators.

Comment: @user5713492 First off, no "moderator" has deleted your answer.  Second, the question was closed as a duplicate by the "Community" user, which implies that the asker of the question cast a vote to close the question as a duplicate.  This seems to indicate that the linked question resolved their issue.  Finally, while I agree that the two questions are not the same, the proof technique is substantially the same, and it does not seem unreasonable (to me, anyway) to link the two questions).  Personally, I might have linked in the other direction, but it makes little difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest path to my mind is to say that since $mg(x)\le f(x)g(x)\le Mg(x)$ for $x\in(a,b)$ then
$$m\int_a^bg(x)dx\le\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\le M\int_a^bg(x)dx$$
On division we get
$$m\le\frac{\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx}{\int_a^bg(x)dx}=c\le M$$
Multiplying back we get
$$\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=c\int_a^bg(x)dx$$
Notice that if $\int_a^bg(x)dx=0$ this method of proof was invalid but we can see from the first inequality that $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=0$ anyhow so any $c\in[m,M]$ would satisfy the hypothesis of the theorem.